# Allow unauthenticated access to certain file types in ASP.NET web.config, regardless of their location

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config, forms-authentication, asp.net-authorization

We deny unauthenticated access by default with:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Then allow certain locations like:

```
<location path="login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

But we actually need to allow access to *all* CSS files, regardless of where they are (for Auryc session replays).

I know I could allow them like this:

```
<location path="folder/whatever.css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

But the problem is they are scattered all over the place, not contained in one folder.

**Is there an easy way to allow all requests of a certain file type (like .css)?**  Or am I stuck having to add and maintain a separate entry for each individual file?